# Create user if it does not exist with Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have created two simple resources which are part of the main.tf file:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "super_admin" {
  count = var.super_admin ? 1 : 0
  name  = "super_admin"
}

data "aws_iam_user" "super_admin" {
  count     = var.super_admin ? 0 : 1
  user_name = "super_admin"
}
```

The first block checks if super_admin is created, if not create him.
The second block checks if super_admin was created, if so then do nothing.
Maybe I miss something, anyway it was my intention.

Currently it does not work and throws error:

```
│ Error: getting user: NoSuchEntity: The user with name super_admin cannot be found.
│       status code: 404, request id: 11bf9e73-690c-454b-b739-a71ed56e9315
│
│   with data.aws_iam_user.super_admin[0],
│   on main.tf line 14, in data "aws_iam_user" "super_admin":
│   14: data "aws_iam_user" "super_admin" {
```

My intention is to create the super_admin user if it does not exist using `1 : 0` just for learning purposes and to better understand how it works.

Comment: you don't need the `data` block, you can just use the `resource` block to check if the iam user exists, create it otherwise it won't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Terraform configuration should not typically have both a `resource` block and a `data` block referring to the same object, because a `resource` block declares that this configuration is going to directly manage something while a `data` block declares that you want to use an object that is managed somewhere else (either in another Terraform configuration, or not with Terraform at all).

If you *do* want to include both in the same configuration then you'll need to help Terraform understand that the two depend on one another by adding a reference between them:

```
resource "aws_iam_user" "super_admin" {
  count = var.super_admin ? 1 : 0

  name  = "super_admin"
}

data "aws_iam_user" "super_admin" {
  count = var.super_admin ? 0 : 1

  user_name = aws_iam_user.super_admin.name
}
```

When one resource refers to another like this, Terraform infers that actions for the first must happen before actions for the second. Terraform should therefore plan to read the object for the `data` block only during the apply phase, because it must wait for the changes related to the `resource` block to have been applied first.

However, it's rare that you should need to write something like the above. There's no need to "check" that an object was created, because the `hashicorp/aws` provider (which owns the implementation of `aws_iam_user`) will return an error itself if the creation fails. If you need to use data about this user, such as its ARN, elsewhere in the configuration then you can refer directly to the `resource` block:

```
aws_iam_user.super_admin.arn
```

Comment: Thanks @Sibtain and @Martin Atkins for your input.

Meanwhile I resolved it by adding that block which works:
resource "aws_iam_user" "super_admin" {
  count = var.super_admin == "" ? 0 : 1
  name  = var.name
}

Thanks Martin for the advice about not using data and resource which are referring to the same object. Also, the fact that this is not real use-case. I wanted play a bit with 1:0 to understand how it works based on example with `aws_iam_user`. I started to learn Terraform several weeks ago.